# Chrome for iOS window.innerHeight is set incorrectly after orientation change

Tags: ios, google-chrome, viewport

Here is the simplest react application to illustrate that with no styling applied at all:

```
import * as React from 'react'

function App() {
    const [message, setMessage] = React.useState(getString())
    React.useEffect(() => {
        const handleResize = () => {
            setMessage(getString())
        }
        window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize)

        return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize)
    })

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <header className="App-header">
                <p>
                    {message}
                </p>
            </header>
        </div>
    );
}

function getString() {
    return 'The viewport size is ' + window.innerWidth + 'x' + window.innerHeight + '.'
}

export default App;
```

I could have used console.log, but it's not easily reproducible on Chrome for iOS, v94.

If you rotate your phone several times, you can have wrong viewport size, like '414x358' for my iPhone 11 instead of '800x358' (landscape) and '414x724' (portrait). On my bigger application I sometimes get something like '800x566'. Seems like probability to get the wrong value depends on page size and complexity - the bigger it is, the higher chance to get wrong dimensions.

Chrome for Android, Chrome for Desktop in emulation mode or Safari are not affected, viewport is always accurate there.

Comment: Crosslink to the Google Community Forum - https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/130340151/incorrect-innerheight-after-orientation-change?hl=en